# How to paste value to the JTextArea in a table like way?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jtextarea

I have a list of values

```
String [] name = {"Peter", "Alexander the Great", "Li" ... };
String [] address = {"10, Main St, NY", "", "none", "IL"};
............
```

These values have different number of characters (some address values could be 50 characters or longer, other could be empty strings.

Currently I am pasting these values to a .csv file and the layout is ok because I separate them with commas. How can I build a nice table in the JText Area?

Comment: *"How can I build a nice table in the JText Area?"*  Use a nice `JTable` instead.

Comment: but the number of rows is uncertain ... this is a gui and the table gets new rows every second

Comment: *"but the number of rows is uncertain"*  So what?  Data can be dynamically added to, or removed from, a table.  The rows always have 2 columns, right?

Comment: Yes only two columns. Should I `add` Jtables to JScrollPane?

Comment: Yes.  Definitely add the table to a scroll pane.  When you do that, the column headers appear correctly (and it provides other good things like ..well, scrolling ability).